# Why, after calling rtcPeerConnection.createOffer(), is the offer null on Safari iOS?

Tags: safari, webrtc, mobile-safari

My code is

```
const localMediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
const rtcPC = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers: ... );
localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => rtcPC.addTrack(track, localStream)); 
const offer = await rtcPC.createOffer();
rtcPC.setLocalDescription(offer);  
console.log('offer=====', rtcPC.localDescription);                            /// displays null
```

This works fine on Chrome but on iOS Safari 13.5.1 the returned offer is always null.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen complaints from `getUserMedia` in Safari. Can you confirm it works on your side?

Comment: Can you add try catch and print the error you see?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `rctPC.setLocalDescription()`. In Chrome this appears to act immediately, even though the spec says it resolves a Promise when the set has completed. In iOS it is not immediate, so I need to follow the spec and wait for the promise to resolve before localdescription is available.